# Unable to use VisualVMLauncher with IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, visualvm

Here are my environment details:

- **IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.3** (Ultimate Edition)
- Build #IU-182.4323.46, built on September 3, 2018
- JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b8 amd64
- JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
- Windows 10 10.0
- Plugin: **VisualVM Launcher** (1.10.138.2210)

---

When I click on the launcher icon from Run tab, I get exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: appId=340470814268910, jdkHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151, visualVmHome=C:\dev\visualvm_141\bin\visualvm.exe
    at krasa.visualvm.VisualVMHelper.startVisualVM(VisualVMHelper.java:53)
    at krasa.visualvm.action.StartVisualVMConsoleAction.actionPerformed(StartVisualVMConsoleAction.java:46)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:220)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:237)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.actionPerformed(ActionButton.java:204)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.performAction(ActionButton.java:146)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.processMouseEvent(ActionButton.java:388)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6313)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4903)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4725)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4725)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:781)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:718)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:382)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\dev\visualvm_141\bin\visualvm.exe": CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:485)
    at krasa.visualvm.VisualVMHelper.openInVisualVM(VisualVMHelper.java:132)
    at krasa.visualvm.VisualVMHelper.startVisualVM(VisualVMHelper.java:51)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 42 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the issue (and the fix).
Posting here so anyone else can benefit from it.

Fix:

1. Allow you current windows user full access to the visualvm.exe (by
   right clicking on it and modifying it's properties on the security
   tab)
2. Start IntelliJ Idea as an administrator